# Inconsistent doc count

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I am running Elasticsearch 1.5.2

I indexed 6,761,727 documents in one of my indexes.

When I run the following query....

```
GET myindex/mytype/_search
{
    "size": 0
}
```

The hits.total count keeps alternating between 2 values...

```
"hits": {
    "total": 6761727,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
}
```

and

```
"hits": {
    "total": 6760368,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
}
```

No matter how many times I run the query the count goes back and forth between the 2.

I searched around a bit and found out that it seems that primary vs replica shards don't have exact same number of docs. If I use preference=primary then the doc count returned is correct.

What is the easiest way to check which shard is the culprit and try to fix him without re-indexing everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the replica count to 0 for that index

```
PUT /my_index/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  }
}
```

wait to see no more replicas for that index when you do `GET /_cat/shards/my_index?v` and then set back to the initial number of replicas.

This will delete all the replicas for that index and then make a new copy of the primaries.

Comment: So yeah I looked at the logs and one of the nodes had disconnected temporarily while indexing. So it caused the issue.